# Get The Static Screen Width of A Device Using Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, width, screen

I am returning image quality on my webpage based on the physical width of a device. This value should be static. The most reliable solution I know so far must be `screen.width` property.

However, in the current Firefox I am using, the value of `screen.width` is not static. When I switched to responsive design view (or `ctrl + shift + m`), then querying `screen.width`, the value corresponded to current viewport width, not the real physical width.

I noticed this when switching to the responsive design view, and reload the page, all images were blurred, having very bad quality.

So, is there some way I can get the static or real physical screen width of a device using pure Javascript? Maybe a tiny library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen.availWidth` and `screen.availHeight` will give you the actual available width and height